# How to create data out of two other data?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to make a Card data type. The problem I am having is that I currently have the cards set up as a "CardValue" and a "Suit" data type which are each separate, and then I was trying to make a "Card" data type that is essentially just (CardValue, Suit). I need the "Card" data to be data and not type so that I can make it an instance of show, but I do not know if this is possible the way I am doing this. Is there a way to make a single Card data that would have every possible card in a deck without going "data Card = AceHeart | AceSpade | AceClub ... etc."?

Here is what I have so far:

```
data CardValue = Ace | Two | Three
               | Four | Five | Six 
               | Seven | Eight | Nine 
               | Ten | Jack | Queen 
               | King deriving (Bounded, Enum, Show, Eq, Ord)

data Suit = Clubs | Spades | Hearts | Diamonds deriving (Show, Eq)

data Card = (CardValue, Suit)

instance Show Card where
    show (v, s) = show v ++ " of " ++ show s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you just got the syntax slightly wrong.

Just write

```
data Card = Card CardValue Suit
```

instead (note that the second "Card" in the above code could also be called something else; The left side names the type, the right side is a name for *values* of type card), and then you can write your show instance as

```
instance Show Card where
    show (Card v s) = show v ++ " of " ++ show s
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you use `data` you define a new data type. You thus will need to specify a data constructor. You can *not* use the tuple data constructor `(,)` here.

You thus can define:

```
data Card = Card CardValue Suit
```

Then you can for example implement an instance of `Show`:

```
instance Show Card where
    show (Card v s) = show v ++ " of " ++ show s
```

That being said, `Show` is usually supposed to generate output that is Haskell code (so you can for example inject it back in the interpreter).

It might be better to define a class:

```
class Representable a where
    repr :: a -> String
```

and thus implement this for `Card` as:

```
instance Representable Card where
    repr (Card v s) = show v ++ " of " ++ show s
```

Comment: That is a good suggestion with the repr because I was just treating show as a sort of print function but this is much smarter.